# Understanding C#'s Type converting

Tags: c#

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

Classes:

```
public abstract class BaseObj
{

    public bool IsValid => GetValidationErrors().Count == 0;
}

public class BaseObjWithId: BaseObj 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseReference<T> : BaseObj where T : BaseObjWithId
{

    public T ObjReference { get; set; }

}

public class Foo: BaseObjWithId
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class FooRef : BaseReference<Foo>
{

}
```

Code-Statement:

```
    BaseReference<BaseObjWithId> foo= new FooRef();
```

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type...

This works:

```
    BaseReference<Foo> foo= new FooRef();
```

But I don't understand why, because Foo is a BaseObjWithId...

Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Surely its because Foo is BaseObjectWithID with extras, and fooRef uses foo, BaseObjWithId is a lesser version its not the same

Comment: Because it makes no sense what you are trying to do. You can cast it though, but it has no purpose.

Comment: Since `FooRef` is tied to the instance of concrete class `Foo`, there's no way to tie it with its base class until and unless you make FooRef too generic, this is less about type conversion more about Generics

Comment: Just because `Foo` inherits from `BaseObjWithId` it doesn't mean that `BaseReference<Foo>` inherits from `BaseReference<BaseObjWithId>` - it doesn't - they are two different types.

Comment: A `Cage<Animal>` is a cage that can house any animal. An `Aquarium` is a `Cage<Fish>`.  So can you use a `Cage<Animal>` where you need an `Aquarium`?  No; an aquarium guarantees that only fish come out, but a `Cage<Animal>` could release a tiger. Can you use an `Aquarium` where you need a `Cage<Animal>`?  No. You can put a giraffe into a `Cage<Animal>` but not into an `Aquarium`.  Since the conversion in both directions is impossible, there must be *no* type relationship between `Aquarium` and `Cage<Animal>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how generics works in relation to type inheritance. You can cast an object of type `FooRef` into a reference of type `BaseReference<Foo>` because `FooRef` inherits from `BaseReference<Foo>`. However, you cannot cast a `BaseReference<Foo>` into a `BaseReference<BaseObjWithID>` because unlike the types they are using as generic type arguments, those two generic classes have no such connection.

Take the following example:

```
public class Fruit {}
public class Apple : Fruit {}
```

Any `Apple` object can be stored in a `Fruit` reference because inheritance ensures that the relationship between them checks out:

```
Fruit f = new Apple();
```

However, where generics are involved, each time a generic version of a class is created with a different type argument, those versions are all treated as completely different types. For example, while the above implicit casting would work, the following would fail:

```
List<Fruit> f = new List<Apple>();
```

`List<Fruit>` and `List<Apple>` are completely different classes. There is no direct conversion between them, implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 1):

What are you searching for, called [`covariance`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). In your case - covariance in generics. According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) it is only implemented for the limited set of types:

this works fine:

```
IEnumerable<Derived> b = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> a = b;
```

this does not work:

```
IList<Derived> b = new List<Derived>();
IList<Base> a = b;
```

So, in your case, `FooRef` is directly derived from `BaseReference<Foo>`, so it can be casted to this type, while c# can not simply cast `BaseReference<Foo>` to `BaseReference<BaseObjWithId>` because of problems with generic arguments covariance.

There could be some workarounds, separated method with hardcoded conversion from one type to another, but, I guess, this behaviour should be avoided at all.